# Can't Ubuntu's grub2 display in menu and load multiple different partitions of windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

I have been using Ubuntu and Windows on the same machine for over a decade now.  In the past I had the latest LTS Ubuntu and XP on their own hard drive partitions.  I used XP for gaming and Ubuntu for safer web and social networking.  It is a setup that has worked very well for me.  My issue came when I decided to buy and install Windows 10 to also dual boot with Ubuntu and XP (keeping for legacy software). So I installed Windows 10 to it's own partition and restored grub2.

The problem is (perhaps there is no way around this?) when grub2 boots it only shows Windows 10 and Ubuntu.  If I want to boot XP I have to first load grub2 and chose Windows 10 which gives me the option to boot XP once Windows 10 had loaded.  If I chose XP, Windows 10 will reboot the computer and load Grub 2 again.  I then chose windows 10 and XP loads instead of 10 (for the one boot only).  It's a double boot EVERY time I want to load XP and very clunky.  I was wondering is there a way to get grub2 to list and boot Ubuntu/XP/Windows 10 separately from the grub2 menu?

Comment: Windows in BIOS mode only boots from the one primary NTFS partition with the boot flag. Easier to move boot flag and install 2nd version to its own partition. Then you have two sets of boot files for grub to find. Not sure if you can convert XP back as Windows 10 has converted XP partition to Windows 10, both boot files & PBR or partition boot sector. But if Windows 10 is in primary partition, you can move boot flag to it and run repairs to install boot files to that partition. Then see if XP repairs can fix the XP install. If Windows 10 not in primary, then nothing you can do.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Is everything on one single drive? Can you please share the output of `sudo parted -l`?